# Simle regex question, c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know how to get only the numbers and the _ from `"{\"id\":\"21432413214_124533451397\"}"` using regular expressions in c#. Here for example, I want the "21432413214_124533451397"-part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0-9]+_[0-9]+` matches two numbers with an underscore between them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to parse JSON. You can use the c# built in JSON deserializing utilities, if you're parsing a more complex object than what you've described above:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
@"""\d+_\d+"""
```

Comment: This doesn't match 222_333, it does match 2____333. In addition, this requires double quotation marks immediately before and after the numbers.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: Yeah, I saw my typo, took 13 minutes to fix due to site crashing and lagging, etc...